# Making tabs, buttons, or neither?

Tags: android, button, android-tabhost

I'm not really sure what tools I should be using to create a desired outcome...

At the bottom of the screen I would like to have three buttons, something like what is at the bottom of this screen except only using text instead of icons, and only having three options, not four.

[image]

Is this a tab view?  I don't need a tab view because I don't need the tabs to stay on screen after one is clicked.

Comment: This might be a tabview. You can just use a linearlayout or something if you just want buttons and not actually tabs. What's your question?

Comment: I am unsure of how I would go about recreating something like this.  I need some transparent-like buttons at the bottom of my screen but using text instead of icons.

Comment: Have you thought about just creating an Options menu that pops up when the user presses the Menu button on the device? It's not very pretty but easy to code and will come and go as needed.

Comment: @Mister, I thought of possibly doing that, but I am actually going off of a pre-decided user interface and have to build it like the mock-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [layout source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/DeskClock.git;a=blob;f=res/layout/desk_clock_buttons.xml;h=9d722820ce4e3f4115652b28185b6b11e5c17b31;hb=3d4de660d654fee760cf96f609198489e4d6525d) for the DeskClock they are indeed image buttons in a linear layout.  The [main layout source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/DeskClock.git;a=blob;f=res/layout/desk_clock.xml;h=271dc65fcc597d8f628a26de64be42a04fc75a27;hb=3d4de660d654fee760cf96f609198489e4d6525d) shows that the buttons are 'included' with the main layout.   Hopefully this source helps.

Comment: Thats good to know, that answers my question perfectly.  Thank you.